# How do I get my normal Find/Replace window back in Visual Studio 2010?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, find, replace

I have no idea what prompted this, but now in VS, I have a horrible find/replace window that pops up and rarely even works.  How do I get the normal one back?

[image: broken find and replace]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have installed the Pro Power Tools. I can tell from your file tabs. Under Tools, Options, you can control individual pieces of the pack. Turn off the Quick Find.

[image]

You might need to scroll to get to it.

Comment: You are the greatest person on the planet today... thank you!

Comment: *blush* You're welcome. BTW, you might want to check out Dev11, which incorporates most of Pro Power Tools, and if the Quick Find doesn't work for you, file Connect bugs on it ASAP. It will be the new normal.